# Make bottom layout stay on bottom when keyboard is displayed while other layouts move up

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, keyboard

Under you will the screenshots illustrating the starting layout, my current result which I am NOT happy with, and the result I want to have:

**This is the opening layout which is perfect:**

[image]

**Then comes the current layout I get when displaying the keyboard which I am NOT happy with:**

[image]

**Then the result that I WANT:**

[image]

Is the a line of code that will make the bottom layout ignore the `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"`? Or how can I do this?

***UPDATE:***

**This is what I get with `adjustPan`:**

[image]

Comment: have you tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` ?

Answer (score 0):

because you are using

`adjustResize`,

So the window is getting resize to make space for keyboard
you should use

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

with this window will not resize and current focus will never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing.

Answer (score 0):

set  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
in your Layout for example ScrollView in my layout

add in manifest

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:weightSum="1">



    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_search"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="@string/test_search"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</RelativeLayout>
```